Can not run file ELF with no extension
I've tried to resolve this issue by my own but encountered nothing anyway. I've even created GitHub rep where I uploaded this confusing app - https://github.com/mophun-one/mophun-rep.
So, the issue is:
I used Ubuntu 22.04 and upon runing "agadir" programm (can be found on link above) as executable file (chmod +x), I experienced the following error:
bash: ./agadir: cannot execute: required file not found.

Noteworthy that the downloaded file is not executable and it outputs "permission denied" message upon running and the developer implies that license is academic and link for download has no limitations.

I am a bit confused about what your facing so can you copy and paste the exact error. Also note you need to make a file executable before you can run it. Where did you get the app from, they must have some documentation.

Welcome to ASK. I took a look at your link. That is a single elf (exectuable file). What rig was used to generate it? What is it likely to do if it does successfully run? I wouldn't be about to mess with that without knowing what it might do.

Ty for such a quick response. George, of course I've tried to make it executable and I wrote (above) what has happened. Anyway, the exact errors are (1) bash: ./agadir: "permission denied" and (2) bash: ./agadir: cannot execute: required file not found for non-executable and executable ones respectively.

Dear David. I don't think to be afraid of running that file because it was downloaded from bona fide source belonging to academia satellite. I expect this software takes some short string of letters and it outputs an exact number. I have no idea how to get any manual on it. Till this time it was sort of cloud service where aforementioned actions took place directly on their site but to date developers decided to switch the access model and introduced subscribtion wiping any accounts. As apologies for prior users they just give this linux link with lack of explanation.

This link can still be used to download it: https://agadir.crg.es/node/732/download/deafe725928334e05e19ab52ae7611f6

In case it helps, the file name (unchanged) has a unprintable character(s) in it (at the end). If you change the name make sure you delete this character first. To examine the libraries it evokes run ldd on it. So type 'ldd ./adadir' then TAB to complete then RETURN.

@david. I am not sure I've done it right but It returns: not a dynamic executable

That suggests its corrupt. download another copy and try again. I get::  linux-gate.so.1 (0xeb675000)::
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xeb652000)::
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xeb548000)::
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xeb30c000)::
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xeb677000)

First you need to download the agadir_linux.zip file
Open a terminal and run in it:
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://agadir.crg.es/system/files/agadir_linux.zip

Then you need to unzip the file, in the same terminal and without changing directories, run:
unzip agadir_linux.zip

This command will extract the agadir file from the agadir_linux.zip file
Next, in the same terminal and without changing directories, rename the file and make it executable, by running:
mv agadir agadir.elf
chmod +x agadir.elf

Next, run it with the command:
./agadir.elf

The error message is certainly confusing. I interpret it as trying to inform you that a key component of the runtime environment required to run the program is missing.
This is likely because Ubuntu does not have the installation of the additional libraries required to run the program enabled by default.
If this is the case, the following commands should solve the problem, open a terminal and run:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

Agadir is a prediction algorithm based on the helix/coil transition theory.
Agadir predicts the helical behavior of monomeric peptides. It only considers short-range interactions. Conditions such as pH, temperature, and ionic strength are used in the calculation. Modifications of the terminals are also allowed.
The representation of an amino acid (aa) sequence can be represented in several ways, by the names of its amino acids, by a letter code, or by another graphical representation.
An example is the aa sequence of the natural 10 aa peptide called GnRH-releasing hormone, which is as follows:
pGlutamic acid-Histidine-Tryptophan-Serine-Tyrosine-Glycine-Leucine-Arginine-Proline-Glycine–NH2
in three-letter code:
pGlu-His-Trp-Ser-Tyr-Gly-Leu-Arg-Pro-Gly–NH2

in one-letter code:
pE-H-W-S-Y-G-L-R-P-G–NH2

The amino acid sequence is known as the primary structure of the protein. The sequence of amino acids that forms a protein ultimately determines its three-dimensional structure and function.

It is not clear why you need to rename the executable.

The file is a 32bit executable, it will not run if the needed libraries are not installed.

I did the whole procedure, the ELF files, I know it's a .elf, because I explored it with Midnight Commander, should have the extension .elf. I use MxLinux 23.4 and Siduction, both with XFCE 4.20 and in both it ran without problems, once the procedure was done. I invite you to do it in Ubuntu and report back.

I've harnessed entire @kyodake sequence but finally faced smth many times seen: bash: ./agadir.elf: cannot execute: required file not found. Should I have installed any Software prior?

@Alejandro Ponomarev: Check out the edit in the post

I've tried above sequence. Unfortunately, the same issue is still on board: bash: ./agadir.elf: cannot execute: required file not found. Yet herewith last command replied error: E: Unable to locate package libncurses5:i386. Anyway I am so thankful to you @kyodake for your endeavour

Minor clarification. I use Ubuntu OS deployed on virtual machine. Can it somehow interfere the result?

@Alejandro Ponomarev: In principle no. If you have the possibility to create a new virtual machine, try one with: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/latest/download, in this distribution, which is the one I use, it runs perfectly.

Ty for the link. Upon deployment new VM I will post. Am I right that I do not need to make last steps on MX-linux and adding .elf to agadir and then make it executable would be enough?

@Alejandro Ponomarev: Aside from exploring it to see what it was about, and searching for ELF files, after downloading and unzipping it, I just added the extension and made it executable and with ./agadir.elf, in the directory that contains it it was executed. It asked: Do you want to test a range of experimental conditions for your peptides?. If yes type Y. Default, N - Do you want to calculate the energy of a particular sequence segment, or do you want to determine the helical content?. If yes type Y. and that's as far as I got because I don't have any peptides.

@kyodake it seems I step forward to acomplish that. At least I've deployed MX and I managed to run it and it asked to me! One more question, it asks me: "type the name of the file with peptide names, conditions and sequence in one letter code and press Enter". What is the file (type?) should be? Should I make common .txt via touch or smth else?

@Alejandro Ponomarev: I have no idea about this, according to their website: You must submit one or more peptide sequences in single letter format. Sequences must be separated by a return character. Spaces and tabs are automatically removed. Only standard amino acids are accepted. Agadir accepts two modifications at the N-terminus (acetylation or succinylation) and one at the C-terminus (amidation). I don't know what that means.
